# MVC escape razor output

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have been trying to escape razor code so that is outputs the category in middle of the file name.

```
<div class="headerpost" style='background-image: url(~/CategoryImages/'@Model.Category'.jpg);'>
```

So that it appears like /CategoryImages/Orders.jpg in the background-image style.
I have tried several escape characters & "" + none of them work.

Comment: What does that render? Also, those `''` shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format need to be

```
<div class="headerpost" style='background-image: url(~/CategoryImages/@(Model.Category).jpg);'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="headerpost" style="background-image: url('~/CategoryImages/@(Model.Category).jpg');">
```

Check the single quotes in this code, it should be on whole URL part.

Comment: You should try the code first (_string' does not contain a definition for 'jpg' and no extension method 'jpg' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found_)